# Accessing Windows share over VPN sort of slow

Tags: windows-8, vpn, windows-8.1, network-shares, windows-server-2012

I have a server at home running Windows Server 2012 Standard (RTM). The server is accessible via VPN (SSTP) over the internet. This works pretty well.

But when I access one of the shared folders from another computer (Windows 8 Enterprise RTM) using the VPN, the connection is sort of slow. "Sort of" because it is not really slow but kind of choppy (hard to describe as I'm no native speaker). I found this out while listening to an audio file from my server. My internet connection at home has 1 Mbps upstream - which should be enough for streaming an MP3 with 192 kbps to another machine. Although, playing the file over the internet doesn't really work. Every 10-30 seconds, the music stops and continues after a few seconds, like a buffer underrun. I then tried to copy the file to the local computer first and found out that even the copying is choppy. The progress bar stops for about 10 seconds, advances 1 MB, then stops again and so on. The whole copy dialog is pretty unresponsive the whole time. Cancelling a copy job took 15 seconds.

Then I wanted to find out whether it is really a problem with the shares. So I downloaded a file from my server again - but this time using HTTP and IIS (and still using the VPN). This download worked as expected: a smooth download with a constant transfer rate of ~1 Mbps.

So what is the problem with those shares? Local shares work perfectly on both machines. So do downloads via HTTP in the VPN. Just the shares via VPN are having problems.

***Update:*** Still having the same problem with Windows 8.1 Enterprise on the client machine.

Comment: 1 Mbps is not really that fast of an upload speed. I'm going to assume its the max your provider advertised to you can expect it to be a true speed of about 80% of that. (800 Kbps). Furthermore, the vpn protocol etc has some overhead. It is true that that wouldnt explain the 192 kbps mp3 not streaming but it is plausible. What network are you on when streaming it from? Is it a work or school network perhaps, what are thier security or bandwidth settings?

Comment: 1 Mbps is what my ISP advertised, indeed, but in the third and fourth paragraph, you can read that I definitely get this speed as long as I don't use a Windows Share. I'm streaming to my work network (~150 Mbps downstream, same ISP as I have at home).